# How to turn string output from sql to integer?

Tags: sql, laravel-5, count

I am generating charts using google chart api. I have done it locally and successfully produce the charts. However, when I transfer them to server (cpanel) the charts is ruined. I have detected that the output of sql query for generating the charts value is produced in string format with "6".

This is the code to get the charts' value:

```
   public function gender()
{
$data = DB::table('results')
   ->select(
    DB::raw('gender as gender'),
    DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
   ->groupBy('gender')
   ->get();
   //dd($data);
 $array[] = ['Gender', 'Number'];
 foreach($data as $key => $value)
 {
  $array[++$key] = [$value->gender, $value->number];
 }
 //dd($array);
 return view('gender')->with('gender', json_encode($array));
}
```

In my local, I try to access the data of the sql using dd($data); producing:

```
 Collection {#263 ▼
 #items: array:2 [▼
 0 => {#264 ▼
  +"gender": "female"
  +"number": 6
}
1 => {#266 ▼
  +"gender": "male"
  +"number": 6
}
]
}
```

I tried accessing in server using same dd($data);

```
  Collection {#260 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
0 => {#261 ▼
  +"gender": "female"
  +"number": "6"
}
1 => {#263 ▼
  +"gender": "male"
  +"number": "6"
}
]
```

The difference is the number value from server code is in string.

Why this happened and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. It seems it's a PHP issue. Are you running the same PHP versions on local and production?

In any case, you could also explicitly cast it as an UNSIGNED integer. I was able to do that with the following:

```
$data = DB::table('results')
   ->selectRaw('gender as gender, CAST(count(*) AS UNSIGNED) as number')
   ->groupBy('gender')
   ->get();
```

Comment: Even if you cast it as an `int`? See my updated answer.

Comment: it produce error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int) as number from `results` group by `gender`' at line 1 (SQL: select gender as gender, CAST(count(*) AS int) as number from `results` group by `gender`)

Comment: my php version 7.1 but server 7.2

Comment: How about if you use CONVERT? I am at a loss actually.

Comment: if I use the same php version, is it solved the problem?

Comment: Irrespective of this issue, your local and production environment should always match.